# Total distance traveled by particle from [0, 8] given position equation

Tags: calculus

s(t) = t^3 - 11t^2 + 24t + 100;

I got the derivative for s(t), which is

v(t) = 3t^2 - 22t + 24;

so the particle changes position @ t = 6 and t = (8/6)

I then plugged in 0, (8/6), 6, and 8, sepretlay back into the s(t) equation

the sum of all those number gave me: 378

however my worksheet states the answer is about 101.62

where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the sum of all those number gave me: 378
>
> however my worksheet states the answer is about 101.62
>
> where did I go wrong?

That is where you went wrong.

You want the *distance travelled between those times*, **not** the *sum of displacements at those times*.

Add up the *absolutes* of how far you go up, how far you go down, and how far you go up again.

$$\def\abs#1{\bigl\lvert #1 \bigr\rvert}\begin{align} L &=  \abs{s(8/6)-s(0)}+\abs{s(6)-s(8/6)}+\abs{s(8)-s(6)}\\ &= \abs{3100/27-100}+\abs{64-3100/27}+\abs{100-64} \\ &= 400/27 + 1372/27 + 36\\ &= 2744/27\\&\approx101.6{\small3}\end{align}$$

---

Another way to look at it: You begin and end at the same displacement (100).  Therefore the total distance traveled is twice difference between the highest and lowest displacement (the only two turnovers). That is $2\cdot(3100/27- 64)$, which is $2744/27$.